# What kind of tree is the giant tree in Downton Abbey?

Tags: downton-abbey

In the opening sequences of Downton Abbey series 1 and 2 there is a **massive** tree near the house. When it appears in the show characters are often shown sitting on a bench underneath it. What kind of tree is it?

[image]

Comment: Never seen the show but does this tree provide some plot significance or is it just a piece of scenery?

Comment: It's just scenery, but a couple of key conversations take place under it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a [Lebanon Cedar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanon_Cedar).   From the wikipedia page about [Highclere Castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highclere_Castle) - the location for the fictional Downton Abbey.

> The famous 18th century seed collector Bishop Stephen Pococke was a
>   friend and brought Lebanon Cedar seeds from a trip to Lebanon

Comment: I knew it had to be a non-native tree. No English tree classification guides could identify it as a native tree.

Comment: Yeah, quite a few British stately homes and castles have non-native plants and trees as the owners in the 19th and early 20th century liked collecting stuff like that - before the issue of 'invasive species' became more of an issue.

Comment: Thanks. This tree blows my mind every time I see it. For me it is a symbol of the grandeur of the house and family.